# Collapse icon does not change on first click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I need to set collapse icon, so when I click on icon or title open collapse and rotate icon 90deg. I do this, but the problem is when the first time we load a web page and click on title or icon they don't change, but on second and any another click they work. Pls take a look a code. Why this not working? Thnx

```css
.footerMenuMobile .fa {
    transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
  }
.footerMenuMobile .collapsed .fa {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="footerContent">
<div class="row footer_menu">
  <div class="container footer_menu_container">
    <div id="collapseSeconMenu" class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 linkovi_footer wow fadeInDown">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 footerMenuMobile text-left">
        <a class="nasloviFootera" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseS" aria-expanded="true">
          Test <i class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></i>
        </a>
        <div id="collapseS" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 collapse">
          <ul class="footer_menu_list">
            <li><a href="standard" class="openSansLightFont">Test</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 footerMenuMobile text-left">
        <a class="nasloviFootera" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDashboard" aria-expanded="true">
              Test1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></i>
            </a>
        <div id="collapseDashboard" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 collapse">
          <ul class="footer_menu_list">
            <li><a href="dashboard" class="openSansLightFont">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="openSansLightFont" target="_blank">Test1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 footerMenuMobile text-left">
        <a class="nasloviFootera" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTechnology" aria-expanded="true">
              Test2 <i class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></i>
            </a>
        <div id="collapseTechnology" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 collapse">
          <ul class="footer_menu_list">
            <li><a class="openSansLightFont">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a class="openSansLightFont">Test2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A required class has been omitted from the accordion content, this class is `.in`, e.g:

```
<div id="collapseS" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 collapse in">...</div>
```

This class needs to be present on load in order to observe the expected behaviour on first click; only on first click is this class, `.in` added, when it should be removed.

This will load all accordions open.
To circumvent this consider adding the below `.collapse()` [methods](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#methods) to initiate on page load:

```
$('.collapse').collapse({
  hide: true
});
```

**OR**

```
$('.collapse').collapse({
  toggle: true
})
```

Then to avoid the icons from toggling after the aforementioned script has run, consider declaring the following rules:

```
.footerMenuMobile .nasloviFootera:not(.collapsed) .fa {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

**OR**

```
.footerMenuMobile .nasloviFootera[aria-expanded="true"] .fa {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
/*$('.collapse').collapse({
  hide: true
});*/

/** OR **/

$('.collapse').collapse({
  toggle: true
})
```

```css
.footerMenuMobile .fa {
  transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
}

.footerMenuMobile .nasloviFootera:not(.collapsed) .fa {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
/** OR **/
.footerMenuMobile .nasloviFootera[aria-expanded="true"] .fa {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="footerContent">
  <div class="row footer_menu">
    <div class="container footer_menu_container">
      <div id="collapseSeconMenu" class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 linkovi_footer wow fadeInDown">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 footerMenuMobile text-left">
          <a class="nasloviFootera collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseS" aria-expanded="false">
          Test <i class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></i>
        </a>
          <div id="collapseS" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 collapse in">
            <ul class="footer_menu_list">
              <li><a href="standard" class="openSansLightFont">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 footerMenuMobile text-left">
          <a class="nasloviFootera" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDashboard" aria-expanded="false">
              Test1 <i class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></i>
            </a>
          <div id="collapseDashboard" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 collapse in">
            <ul class="footer_menu_list">
              <li><a href="dashboard" class="openSansLightFont">Test1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="openSansLightFont" target="_blank">Test1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 footerMenuMobile text-left">
          <a class="nasloviFootera" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTechnology" aria-expanded="false">
              Test2 <i class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></i>
            </a>
          <div id="collapseTechnology" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 collapse in">
            <ul class="footer_menu_list">
              <li><a class="openSansLightFont">Test2</a></li>
              <li><a class="openSansLightFont">Test2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 footerMenuMobile text-left">
          <a class="nasloviFootera" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTechnologyq" aria-expanded="false">
              Test3 <i class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></i>
            </a>
          <div id="collapseTechnologyq" class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 collapse in">
            <ul class="footer_menu_list">
              <li><a class="openSansLightFont">Test2</a></li>
              <li><a class="openSansLightFont">Test2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Reference:** [Collapse: Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#collapseoptions)